# convert xml value to string (use c#)

Tags: c#, xml

---

in xml file

```
<dummy1>
  <dummy2>
    <dummy3>
      <items>
        <item id="1111" name="Real_item_Name" url="i=1111">
          <filter name="itemLevel" value="item_value"/>
          <filter name="source" value="dummy4"/>
        </item>
       <item id="2222" name="Real_item_Name2" url="i=222">
          <filter name="itemLevel" value="item_value2"/>
          <filter name="source" value="dummy5"/>
        </item>
              //roop 
      </items>
    </dummy3>
  </dummy2>
</dummy1>
```

---

how can i make this value in c#
(insert String value)

Real_item_Name , 1111 , item_value 
Real_item_Name2 , 2222 , item_value2 
Real_item_Name3 , 3333 , item_value3

please show me dom or sax example ...

Comment: You mean hold this xml as string?

Comment: No, he means to turn the XML into a (near) csv equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

There's a dozen different ways to do this. Here's a very simple example using [XSL](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/):

mytransform.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />, <xsl:value-of select="@id" />, <xsl:value-of select="filter/@value" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

We load the XSL file into a transform object; specify an input XML and an output text file:

```
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load("c:\\path\\mytransform.xsl");
xslt.Transform("c:\\path\\input.xml", "c:\\path\\output.txt");
```

Check out the documentation on [XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) for more in-depth usage, like working in memory streams and XML objects instead of file paths. This demonstrates the core concepts though.

Comment: XslTransform is obsolete, use XslCompiledTransform. Syntax is identical.

Comment: Ty: Compiling is faster, but has a high initial cost.

Comment: <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />, <xsl:value-of select="@id" />, <xsl:value-of select="filter/@value" />
  </xsl:template>

This template should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");
string csv = string.Join("\n",
    xml.Descendants("item").Select(item =>
        string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}",
            (string)item.Attribute("name"),
            (string)item.Attribute("id"),
            (string)item.Elements("filter")
                        .Single(f => f.Attribute("name") == "itemLevel")
                        .Attribute("value")))
       .ToArray());
```

Comment: Great! I learn something new. I use this code but an error at Single - XElement doesnot contains a definition. How it can be resolved?

Comment: Given the use of LINQ, may I suggest you also use "var" where possible?

Comment: adatapost, you need to include the right namespaces for LINQ to XML.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I am sorry but I can't resovle this. May be it is belongs to .netframework 4.0

Comment: Thanks ...
where is [Single]'s definition?

Comment: @Steven, I don't see the need for `var` here - there are no anonymous types used, and outside of them, it's a matter of style.

Comment: Regarding missing `Single()` - it should've been `Elements("filter")` rather than `Element("filter")` - I've fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pavel: It's not required by C#, so it would work either way, but using "var" complies with DRY.  Essentially, I don't see any benefit to saying XDocument twice in a row.  In short, I'd treat this as a matter of maintainability rather than style.

Comment: @Steven, if you've seen any discussion on use/misuse of `var` on C# public forums/newsgroups/blogs, you know that it is a very debated issue, and there's no clear consensus on it. Some say what you say; others believe that it hampers readability. Several major style guidelines forbid its use except when it's required by anonymous types; some only allow it when right hand side is `new T`. I've worked on projects that had it both ways, and prefer to stay out of this holywar :)

Comment: @Pavel: You're right that there's some unnecessary heat on this topic.  What I find absurd is that VB.NET has had the equivalent syntax and it's been uncontroversial.